# Discretionary hyphen destroys kerning and ligature

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core, hyphenation, ligatures, kerning

Consider the following example (plain TeX format):

```
VA fi\par
V\-A f\-i
\bye
```

I tried TeX, pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX, but the second line looks the same as the first line only when using LuaTeX. My questions are:

1. Is this an intended behaviour?
2. Is it difficult or impossible to make other TeX engines act like LuaTeX (discretionary hyphen does *not* destroy kerning and ligature)?
3. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: `\discretionary{f-}{i}{fi}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\discretionary{f-}{i}{fi}` seems to work. You can define a macro to ease the use:

```
\def\dfi{\discretionary{f-}{i}{fi}}
\def\VA{\discretionary{V-}{A}{VA}}
VA fi\par
AD\VA NCE Nar\dfi na
\bye
```

Not ideal but if you don't have many problems, you could work with that.

In any case, hyphenation is not something user should worry much in theory, do you have the correct language set in your document? That comes with many rules to tell TeX how to break up words. And you also have `\hyphenation{wordwithf-ibreak wordwithV-Abreak}` to add rules for particular words; it does work well (ligature when not broken, and broken correctly, plus you set it up once for the whole document).

<sub>*Rant/Question*: I don't understand why `\-` is a primitive. What was the need? Couldn't it be just defined in terms of `\discretionary`? It's one of those doubts I have about TeX :)</sub>

Comment: Regarding the claim that `\-` is a primitive: it's not true. Instead, `\-` gets expanded to `\discretionary{-}{}{}`.

Comment: Regarding the last part, I haven't looked into this one, but TeX does contain, for efficiency, primitives that can be defined in terms of others: for example `\hss` (and arguably even `\hfill`).

Comment: @Mico I think it is. Not that it cannot be redefined (in fact it is redefined) but it is a primitive originally. ShreevatsaR, What would be the definition of `\hss`? I always thought `\hfill` was a macro! And another thing that comes to memory is that I don't understand why the particular definition of `\hidewidth` :)

Comment: @Manuel Yes `\-` is a primitive; can try `\show\-` in plain. And on `\hss` (horizontal stretch or shrink): in the TeX 77 manual (*TeX and METAFONT: New Directions in Typesetting*), Appendix X “Recent extensions to TeX” says: ”The new control sequences `\hfil`, `\hfilneg`, `\hss` are short for `\hskip 0pt plus 100000pt`, `\hskip 0pt plus -100000pt`, `\hskip 0pt plus 100000pt minus 100000pt` respectively, and they take less TeX memory space. The vertical analogs are `\vfil`, `\vfilneg` and `\vss`.” (Also, that manual has `\-` but not the more general `\discretionary` which must have come later.)

Comment: (Or in current TeX, we could define `\hfil` as `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil` and `\hss` as `\hskip 0pt plus 1fil minus 1fil`, yet they are primitives because they are/were used so often (in plain TeX) that it makes (or made, at the time) TeX faster to not have to look up this glue in its table or whatever. Anyway I realize this is getting farther and farther away from the topic of this question :-)

Comment: @Manuel - I guess the TeXbook's terminology for what to call `\-` is a bit confusing. In the index, on p. 458, the asterisk next to `\-` indicates that it's a primitive. However, in Chapter 14, on p. 95, we are informed that `\-` is an abbreviation for `\discretionary{-}{}{}`. (Obviously, `\discretionary` *is* a primitive.) I had been under the impression that only primitives don't get expanded, and that's why I had thought that `\-` was not a primitive. However, is it maybe the case of replacing `\-` with `discretionary{-}{}{}` is achieved by some means *other than" expansion?

Comment: @Mico I just checked with `\edef\q{\-}` and it does indeed *expand* (this I thought wouldn't happen), so `\-` is an expandable primitive that expands to `\discretionary{-}{}{}`, but it has been *defined* “by some means other than” `\def\-{\discretionary{-}{}{}}` (although the result is exaclty the same). @ShreevatsaR Thanks for the info ;)

Comment: @Manuel I tried `\edef\q{\-}` and it doesn't expand to anything other than `\-`. Are you sure you tried it in TeX (where `\-` is a primitive) and not in LaTeX (where `\-` has been overwritten, defined as a macro)?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I don't know what I did, but that's what I must've done because otherwise I don't know, but still I had the document written and saved in my computer and now after recompiling indeed it doesn't expand. Can't explain exactly what I've done, but I just recompiled the document hehehe In any case, *yes*, you are right, and that's indeed more logical (as I said I didn't expect `\-` to expand into anything).

Comment: For heaven’s sake, **do not say `\def\fi...`!**

Comment: @GuM It was just an example, but... god, I didn't even think about that!

Comment: Always use `\newcommand` and you’ll not run this kind of risks! ;-)

Comment: @GuM Not in plain TeX :P

Answer (score 17):

By default, the control sequence `\-` is an abbreviation for

```
\discretionary{-}{}{}
```

(see p. 95 of the TeXbook). The first argument of `\discretionary`, the *prebreak*, specifies what gets inserted immediately before the linebreak *if* a linebreak is inserted (here: a hyphen character). The second argument, the *postbreak*, specifies what's inserted immediately after the line break if a linebreak occurs (here: nothing). The third argument, the *nobreak*, specifies what gets typeset *if no linebreak* occurs -- here: nothing or, more precisely and crucially, an empty token, `{}`.

For the sake of specificity, consider the following example: `half\-line`. This first gets expanded to `half\discretionary{-}{}{}line`. Suppose the word does *not* get broken up at the end of a line. What happens next depends on which TeX engine is in use.

- Assuming pdfLaTeX is in use, what gets typeset is `half{}line`, and the `fl` ligature is (correctly!) broken up, since that is what's supposed to happen if `f{}l` is encountered.
- In contrast, under LuaLaTeX all text-mode instances of `{}` are discarded prior to final processing. Therefore, `halfline` is processed without the `{}` between `f` and `l`, and the `fl` ligature is (incorrectly in this case) *not* broken up.
- What happens under XeLaTeX depends partly on the version of XeLaTeX that's in use on your system. E.g., if you use TeXLive2018, `halfline` and `half\-line` are both typeset *with* an fl-ligature if no line break occurs between half and line. At some in the not-too-distant past, though, the fl-ligature was suppressed if `half\-line` was encountered.

To verify these claims, simply compile the following document under pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
halfline half\-line
\end{document}
```

For "plain" pdfTeX, XeTeX, and LuaTeX, simply run

```
halfline half\-line 
\bye
```

To get all three engines to produce the same output, don't write `half\-line`. Instead, write `hal\discretionary{f-}{l}{fl}ine`. That way, the fl-ligature will be used whenever no line break occurs.

Comment: Good morning to you. Why do not see in chat? +1.

Comment: `\-` is a TeX primitive, but LaTeX redefines it, keeping the original in `\@@hyph`.

Comment: @egreg - I find the TeXbook's terminology a bit confusing when it comes to the control sequence `\-`. In the index of the TeXbook, on p. 458,  `\-` is listed as a primitive; however, on p. 95 of the TeXbook, we're told that `\-` is an abbreviation for `\discretionary{-}{}{}`. That's why my inclination was *not* to call `\-` a primitive. Sigh.

Comment: some literate english native speakers would suggest that "halfline" isn't an appropriate word for a ligature, since it's a compound.  (i'm sitting on the fence on this one, but tending toward preferring no ligature.)  a better example might be "affliction", where the "ffl" surely deserves being a single ligature.

Comment: @Sebastiano - Sorry, can't enter the chatroom today, as I'm at a computer located behind a massive firewall. (That's also why my answer contains just text, but no screeshots, since uploading of screenshots is disabled intentionally at my current site...)

Comment: @Mico Knuth admits at the outset to be telling some white lies; actually, `\-` stands for `\discretionary{\char\hyphenchar\font}{}{}`; if a font sets `\hyphenchar` to −1, you get a (possible) break with no character inserted. Which explains why LaTeX redefines it to insert, if `\hyphenchar\font` is negative, the `\defaulthyphenchar`.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for providing this in-depth explanation.

Comment: @Mico And LuaTeX, as expected, has a different primitive action for `\-`. It's essentially `\discretionary{\char\prehyphenchar}{}{}`

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this additional piece of information. The main claim in my answer regarding the behavior of `-` under LuaLaTeX still stands, then: In the nobreak case (3rd arg of `\discretionary`), the `{}` element is discarded by LuaLaTeX, explaining why ligaturing and kerning is taking place for `f\-l`and `V\-A` -- unlike under pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: About `\-` being a primitive, see `tex.web` section 1114 (see also section 208); `\-` and `\discretionary` are two “flavors” (same *eq_type*, but different *equiv*) of the same primitive command.  The different actions of these two flavors correspond to the two branches of the outer **if** in section 1117.  (This comment might interest @egreg too.)

Comment: @GuM You spared me a search! `;-)` By the way, the third doubly dangerous paragraph on page 455 of the TeXbook says that `\-` is equivalent to `\discretionary{\char`​ *h​* `}{}{}`, where *h* is the `\hyphenchar` of the current font.

Comment: @egreg: …and you didn’t need to search for that because p. 455 is the main (underlined) reference for `\-` in the index. ;-)