# What does a backslash hyphen (\-) do?

Tags: syntax

What does `\-` do in the middle of a word? The context in which I saw it was

```
\textsc{Some\-Word}
```

I tried searching for this syntax with google but it's very difficult to get a search engine to do anything with such oddball characters.

Comment: `\-` can be used to mark a possible break/hyphenation point within a word. It is explained rather nicely in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400640/35864

Comment: I believe it is called a [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen).